# Python module os.chmod(file, 664) does not change the permission to rw-rw-r-- but -w--wx----

Tags: python, file, permissions, chmod

Recently I am using Python module os, when I tried to change the permission of a file, I did not get the expected result. For example, I intended to change the permission to rw-rw-r--,

```
os.chmod("/tmp/test_file", 664)
```

The ownership permission is actually -w--wx--- (230)

```
--w--wx--- 1 ag ag 0 Mar 25 05:45 test_file
```

However, if I change 664 to 0664 in the code, the result is just what I need, e.g.

```
os.chmod("/tmp/test_file", 0664)
```

The result is:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ag ag 0 Mar 25 05:55 test_file
```

Could anybody help explaining why does that leading 0 is so important to get the correct result?

Comment: Octal. Octal. Octal.

Comment: I opened an issue for python documentation at http://bugs.python.org/issue25377 because that should be clear from the docs.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Found this on a [different forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=889326)

> If you're wondering why that leading zero is important, it's because
>   permissions are set as an octal integer, and Python automagically
>   treats any integer with a leading zero as octal. So os.chmod("file",
>   484) (in decimal) would give the same result.

What you are doing is passing `664` which in octal is `1230`

In your case you would need

```
os.chmod("/tmp/test_file", 436)
```

---

[Update]  Note, for Python 3 you have prefix with 0o (zero oh). E.G, `0o666`

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused that, 484 in decimal means 744 in octal, which makes sense in the thread you mentioned in the forum. However, if I give 644 in decimal, it goes to 1204 in octal. How does 1204 relate to 230 in octal?

Comment: That was picked up verbatim from the post. I have added what you need (436) in the last part of the answer

Comment: 664 = 1230, and the system picks up the three rightmost digits for setting the permissions

Comment: @AplusG: the `1` is ***not*** discarded! That's the sticky/setuid/setgid bit, and 1 means `sticky`. Using `ls -l` you may notice permissions now include a `T` in the end...

Comment: os.chmod("score.py", eval("0664")) could be all right

Comment: easier to add the 0 and make it octal :)

Comment: Note, for Python 3 you have prefix with 0o (zero oh).

Comment: I use 0o in python 2.7.10

Comment: I think access right is decimal form is very confused, and please never use this.

Comment: The `int()` function can take an extra argument `base`: `os.chmod('/tmp/test_file', int('664', 8))`

Answer (score 154):

So for people who want semantics similar to:

```
$ chmod 755 somefile
```

Use:

```
$ python -c "import os; os.chmod('somefile', 0o755)"
```

If your Python is older than 2.6:

```
$ python -c "import os; os.chmod('somefile', 0755)"
```

Comment: The python3 format works in python 2.7.9 as well. I have not checked earlier versions.

Comment: The Python 3 syntax works back to Python 2.6 https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127-integer-literal-support-and-syntax

Comment: Should probably be `00755`, just to make it clear where the suid/sgid/sticky bits go, in the event that some later developer comes through and wants to make this old script use, for example, sgid with `2755` but then can't figure out why the perms are completely screwed up. ;)

Answer (score 26):

**Use permission symbols (`stat.S_I*`) instead of raw octal numbers**

Your problem would have been avoided if you had used the more semantically named permission symbols rather than raw magic numbers, e.g. for `664`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import stat

os.chmod(
    'myfile',
    stat.S_IRUSR |
    stat.S_IWUSR |
    stat.S_IRGRP |
    stat.S_IWGRP |
    stat.S_IROTH
)
```

This is documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod and the names are the same as the [POSIX C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755) which is also present at `man 2 stat` and `man 2 chmod`:

```
S_IRUSR  (00400)  read by owner
S_IWUSR  (00200)  write by owner
S_IXUSR  (00100)  execute/search by owner
S_IRGRP  (00040)  read by group
S_IWGRP  (00020)  write by group
S_IXGRP  (00010)  execute/search by group
S_IROTH  (00004)  read by others
S_IWOTH  (00002)  write by others
S_IXOTH  (00001)  execute/search by others
```

Another advantage is the greater portability as mentioned in the docs:

> Note: Although Windows supports `chmod()`, you can only set the file’s read-only flag with it (via the `stat.S_IWRITE` and `stat.S_IREAD` constants or a corresponding integer value). All other bits are ignored.

`chmod +x` is demonstrated at: [How do you do a simple "chmod +x" from within python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python/55591471#55591471)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2.

Comment: This is the correct way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: I know this the python way but It hardly could be any uglier :)

Comment: @TomaszSwider In what way? This type of bitflag/bitmasking notation is common in the C world which obviously largely predates Python.

Comment: @RaleighL. Perhaps the S_I noise could have been gone at least now that we have namespaces.

Answer (score 16):

If you have desired permissions saved to string then do

```
s = '660'
os.chmod(file_path, int(s, base=8))
```

Comment: Excellent realistic use case

Answer (score 13):

leading `0` means this is **octal** constant, not the decimal one. and you need an octal to change file mode.

permissions are a bit mask, for example, `rwxrwx---` is `111111000` in binary, and it's very easy to group bits by 3 to convert to the octal, than calculate the decimal representation.

`0644` (octal) is `0.110.100.100` in binary (i've added dots for readability), or, as you may calculate, `420` in decimal.

Answer (score 5):

@mc.dev's answer was the best answer here I ended up leveraging that to make the below function wrapper for reuse.  Thanks for the share.

```
def chmod_digit(file_path, perms):
    """
    Helper function to chmod like you would in unix without having to preface 0o or converting to octal yourself.
    Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60052847/1621381
    """
    os.chmod(file_path, int(str(perms), base=8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the stat.* bit masks does seem to me the most portable and explicit way of doing this. But on the other hand, I often forget how best to handle that. So, here's an example of masking out the 'group' and 'other' permissions and leaving 'owner' permissions untouched. Using bitmasks and subtraction is a useful pattern.

```
import os
import stat
def chmodme(pn):
    """Removes 'group' and 'other' perms. Doesn't touch 'owner' perms."""
    mode = os.stat(pn).st_mode
    mode -= (mode & (stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXO))
    os.chmod(pn, mode)
```