# How can I change the file permissions in Python?

Tags: php, python

I am trying to find the equivalent **Python** code to this **PHP** code, but I'm not sure how to translate the `0640`:

**PHP** code:

```
chmod($credentials_file, 0640);
chown($credentials_file, 'webapp');
```

I'm looking at the os.chmod documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod), but I'm not sure how `0640` equates to `stat.SOMETHING_HERE`. Does anyone have any idea how to port these two lines to **Python**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python module os.chmod(file, 664) does not change the permission to rw-rw-r-- but -w--wx----](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607903/python-module-os-chmodfile-664-does-not-change-the-permission-to-rw-rw-r-bu)

Comment: That answer doesn't discuss the `stat.*` options though. How can I find what `0640` means so that I can use the approach that the docs (references in the question) recommend?

Comment: [CHMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Comment: `0640`: `6` = owner read/writable, `4` = group readable, `0` = others non-readable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0640` is an *octal* number (that is the meaning of the leading `0`, which doesn't count as a digit), and means the following permissions (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes)):

- the first digit is for the file's **owner**, and (as `6` is `110` in binary, where the bits are **r**ead, **w**rite and e**x**ecute permission respectively) means 
  *read and write* permission;
- the second digit is for the **group**, and (as `4` is `100` in binary) means *read-only*; and
- the third digit is for **other** users, and means no permissions (`0` is `000`!)

Therefore in this case you want to combine `S_IRUSR` (user read), `S_IWUSR` (user write) and `S_IRGRP` (group read):

```
>>> import stat
>>> oct(stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IRGRP)
'0640'
```

---

You can see each permission individually by displaying the octal number in binary form:

```
>>> bin(0640)
'0b110100000'
```

This breaks down as follows:

```
 # USR
0b 110 100 000
 # ^ user read (yes)
 #  ^ user write (yes)
 #   ^ user execute (no)

     # GRP
0b 110 100 000
     # ^ group read (yes)
     #  ^ group write (no)
     #   ^ group execute (no)

         # OTH
0b 110 100 000
         # ^ other read (no)
         #  ^ other write (no)
         #   ^ other execute (no)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know (and not what the "possible duplicate" post talks about). Thanks!

Comment: @Brett I've just realised I didn't make explicit that you *can* just use `0640` as the second argument to `os.chmod`; the constants in `stat` are just e.g. `stat.S_IWUSR == 128`, there's nothing special about them.